# ANTLR v4: Same character has different meaning in different contexts

Tags: antlr, grammar, lexer, antlr4

This is my first crack at parser generators, and, consequently ANTLR.  I'm using ANTLR v4 trying to generate a simple practice parser for Morse Code with the following extra rules:

1. A letter (e.g., `...` [the letter 's']) can be denoted as capitalized if a '^' precedes it

   - ex.: `^...` denotes a capital 'S'
2. Special characters can be embeded in parentheses

   - ex.: `(@)`
3. Each encoded entity will be separated by whitespace

So I could encode the following sentence:

> ABC a@b.com

as (with corresponding letters shown underneath):

```
^.- ^-... ^-.-. ( ) ._ (@) -... (.) -.-. --- --
 A   B     C    ' ' a  '@' b    '.' c    o   m
```

Particularly note the two following entities: `( )` (which denotes a space) and `(.)` (which denotes a period.

There is mainly one things that I'm finding hard to wrap my head around: The same token can take on different meanings depending on whether it is in parentheses or not.  That is, I want to tell ANTLR that I want to discard whitespace, yet not in the `( )` case.  Also, a Morse Code character can consist of dots-and-dashes (periods-and-dashes), yet, I don't want to consider the period in `(.)` as "any charachter".

Here is the grammar I have got so far:

```
grammar MorseCode;

file: entity*;

entity:
      special
    | morse_char;

special: '(' SPECIAL ')';

morse_char: '^'? (DOT_OR_DASH)+;

SPECIAL     : .; // match any character
DOT_OR_DASH : ('.' | '-');

WS          : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip; // we don't care about whitespace (or do we?)
```

When I try it against the following input:

```
^... --- ...(@)
```

I get the following output (from `grun ... -tokens`):

```
[@0,0:0='^',<1>,1:0]
[@1,1:1='.',<4>,1:1]
...
[@15,15:14='<EOF>',<-1>,1:15]
line 1:1 mismatched input '.' expecting DOT_OR_DASH
```

It seems there is trouble with ambiguity between `SPECIAL` and `DOT_OR_DASH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your `(@)` syntax behaves like a quoted string in other programming languages. I would start by defining `SPECIAL` as:

```
SPECIAL : '(' .*? ')';
```

To ensure that `. .` and `..` are actually different, you can use this:

```
SYMBOL : [.-]+;
```

Then you can define your `^` operator:

```
CARET : '^';
```

With these three tokens (and leaving `WS` as-is), you can simplify your parser rules significantly:

```
file
  : entity* EOF
  ;

entity
  : morse_char
  | SPECIAL
  ;

morse_char
  : CARET? SYMBOL
  ;
```

Comment: Sure enough, that did the trick...not sure why yet--now to start analyzing.

Comment: So it seems my confusion is in "what do I define as a lexer rule vs. parser rule?".  For instance, you changed "special" to a lexer rule, correct?  Do you have a thought process to help you decide?  Or do I just need to--gulp--practice? lol